# Symfony2 (debug mode) catching vendor exception before I can

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the Klarna SDK to implement their payment methods. The SDK calls the api and checks the response code. If the response-code is not 0 (all codes > 0 are errors) an exception is thrown. In my controller I try to catch the exception to handle it. But in the development enviroment the "exception detected" comes first.

**vendor/.../klarna/.../function.php**

```
public function xy() {
   $status = $this->getResponse();
   if($status > 0) throw new KlarnaException(...);
}
```

**src/AppBundle/Controller/MyController**

```
public function indexAction() {
   $k = new Klarna();
   try {
      $k->xy();
   } catch(Exception $e) {
      die('Something wrent wrong');
   }
}
```

But the catch() is never executed because the execution stopps when detecting the exception in the vendor. How to prevent debuggin vendor classes?

Comment: are you adding a `use \Exception;` in your controller?

Comment: @Rooneyl No, that es the solution - so simple... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony loves namespaces, so if you use any native PHP classes you need to add them using a `use` statement.
So in your case if you want the Exception class, `use \Exception;`
If you where using a DateTime object, `use \DateTime;`